# Comment in REG file

Tags: registry

I know that putting a semicolon at the beginning of a line in a REG file indicates that it's commented. I like to know whether it's possible to put a comment after a line (right-hand of a line)?

Answer (score 65):

It's enough to put semicolon before comment on the same line. In another words, semicolon before comment is supported by reg file on a line with registry entry as well as a full-line of comment.

#### References

- Minus sign to delete, semicolon to comment and IF/ENDIF mentioned here: [MSDN: *Registry File (Compact 2013)*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg469889.aspx) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/n4sj6).)

Comment: I just tested this on the oldest machine I can find, an XP machine (Windows 5.1 build 2600), and it ran, making the changes specified on the commented line and the lines below it.